# How do I fix this modified run-length encoding program?

Tags: python, function, python-itertools, run-length-encoding

Hi im a python noob and i need help

For repeating consecutive characters, I want to return a nested list that represents the [len(x), x] (RLE). I created this program:

```
import itertools
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1]
def function(lst):
    new = []
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst):
        if len(list(g)) > 1:
            new.append([len(list(g)), k])
        else:
            new.append(k)
    return new
print(function(lst))
```

But it seems to return:

```
[[0, 1], 2, 3, [0, 4], 5, 1]
```

Why does it do this, and how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: `g` in your code, the group object, is an iterator. You exhaust it when you call `list()` on it the first time.  You need to calculate the length once and save it to a variable if you need it more than once.

Comment: Once you use `list(g)`, you have exhausted the iterator `g`. Assign `list(g)` to a variable before using it.

Comment: "g" holds an iterator which is exhausted after first conversion to a list. Store the list length before the "if" and use that twice